# CMake Config based condition in a multi config generator

Tags: visual-studio-2012, cmake

I am looking to specify different DLL's to use based on it building in debug or release. for example:

```
 IF CONFIGURATION MATCHES Debug
     SET(MYDLL my_dlld)
ELSE()
     SET(MYDLL my_dll)
ENDIF()
```

I have looked at logical expressions such as

```
$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:DEBUG_MODE>
```

But this did not seem to work, maybe my implementation of it was incorrect. Any help would be greatly appreciated

EDIT: Some minimal code for understanding

```
PROJECT(myproject)

#ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DMANAGER_EXPORTS)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
                     ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/API/mydll
                   )

$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:SET(MYDLL mydlld)>
$<$<CONFIG:Release>:SET(MYDLL mydll)>

SET(LIBS
          ${MYDLL}
   )
```

mydll - Is a pre-generated shared library which has a debug and release version

Comment: Generator expressions are indeed the way to go, but they are only evaluated in certain contexts, and only at generate time. So whether you can use them depends on what you're doing with `MYDLL`. Can you post a [mcve] of your CMake code?

Comment: Edit to try and meet Minimal example

Comment: You've just pushed the problem back 1 step. What are you doing with `LIBS` in the end? **That** is what matters - what is `MYDLL` eventaully used for in your CMake code. Genexes are evaluated in certain contexts like inside `target_link_libraries` etc., but not in general CMake code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a possible solution is that you can do the following

```
#SET(LINK_LIB debug my_dlld optimized my_dll)
#TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(MYDLL ${LINK_LIB})
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: @MikeTarrant: Generator expressions can also be used in this case as value for variable `LINK_LIB`: `$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:my_dlld>$<$<CONFIG:Release>:my_dll>`.